# how to measure leakage current across a zener diode with a transimpedance op amp

Tags: zener, leakage-current, transimpedance

I am trying to measure the leakage current of a SMF36CA zener diode. I am doing this with a transimpedance op amp (LMC6062IM/NOPB).[image]

Attached is the circuit I am using. The amp and diode in the circuit are not the ones I am using, just the ones Circuit lab had.  The diode is a bi-directional one so I put 2 zeners in the circuit to mimic that. The gain resistor is 1G ohms, although I have used a variety of different values. I am trying to measure the leakage current through several different values, from 1v to 40v. The breakdown voltage of that zener is 36. My problem lies, in the fact that when I approach 36 volts the output voltage starts to ramp at a way that is inconsistent with the leakage current graph of that diode. What could I do to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Zener 3.3 V.

See what happens at opamp output. Should see also the negative input of the opamp.
It is "saturated" so don't measure anyway ...

[image]

Be aware that you should not apply an input voltage higher than Vsupply/2 (V1/2).